# Como gerar CPFs randômicos em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, matemática

Preciso de uma classe genérica para gerar CPF válido para enviar valor para campos com o Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Você pode tentar alterar um algoritmo validador de CPF para gerar CPFs.

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade/duvida exatamente?

Comment: Este não é um site para pessoas criarem o código para você. Tente você fazer o código, e se obter algum erro, poste aqui as áreas do código relacionadas com o erro, bem como o erro ocorrendo e o resultado esperado.

Comment: Uma breve explicação de como gerar e como validar CPF válidos também: [www.geradorcpfvalido.com.br/formula-para-gerar-cpf](http://www.geradorcpfvalido.com.br/formula-para-gerar-cpf).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Segue um algoritmo que montei pra gerar um CPF válido em C#:

```
public static class CpfUtils
{
    public static String GerarCpf()
    {
        int soma = 0, resto = 0;
        int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

        Random rnd = new Random();
        string semente = rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999).ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(semente[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];

        resto = soma % 11;
        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        semente = semente + resto;
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(semente[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];

        resto = soma % 11;

        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        semente = semente + resto;
        return semente;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava. Resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi dar uma solução já que a resposta aceita tem alguns problemas. Respondi também para explicar o código, já que sem explicação a resposta tem pouca serventia.

Além de fazer alocações sem necessidade e conversões para `string` e de volta para número, há um problema de não gerar CPFs começando com 0, extremamente comuns, por um erro conceitual de gerar o número todo como se ele fosse um dado numérico, quando na verdade ele é descritivo, e o fato de poder começar com 0 mostra isso. Não vou entrar no assunto aqui, mas já respondi em diversos lugares. Não basta saber criar códigos, é preciso entender os problemas de forma real.

Também resolvi na minha o que a outra resposta identificou que pode gerar CPFs inválidos. Não muito problemático, mas não precisaria testar se tudo é 9 porque este número nunca será gerado já que a [função randômica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) exclui o valor de limite superior, algo que então dá um resultado certo por coincidência.

E fiz uma melhoria permitindo, opcionalmente, você escolher em qual estado deseja que seria emitido o número do CPF, já que tem regra para isto.

Eu só crio uma `string` no final. Gero os dígitos individualmente e trato como número direto o tempo todo.

Eu pensei em alocar o *array* na pilha com [`Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para evitar pressão no *garbage collector*, mas seria um problema porque sem biblioteca externa eu não poderia usar LINQ nele, que eu preferi usar aqui, ainda que ele não seja o máximo de eficiência. Mas de qualquer forma a alternativa teria que usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) no lugar se não usar LINQ, o que será até pior que o *array* no *heap*. Infelizmente o .NET ainda não permite o máximo de eficiência em qualquer caso.

Eu usei alocação no *heap* só com um *array* e a *string* de resultado final contra mais de 20 na solução aceita, isso dá uma diferença enorme, principalmente se tiver que gerar uma quantidade grande de CPFs. A outra solução faz mais ainda.

Dá para melhorar e/ou encurtar um pouco mais, mas é só estilo de código, e isso poderia piorar a eficiência, ainda que de forma irrisória.

Dos 9 dígitos que são usados, sendo o último dependente de uma tabela por unidade da federação, os dois dígitos são calculados somando os valores depois de aplicar um multiplicador começando com 1 a mais que a quantidade de dígitos e que vai decrescendo de acordo com a posição do dígito. O segundo dígito faz o mesmo, mas inclui o primeiro dígito verificador já calculado. Com a soma aplica-se o resto de 11 (número primo mais que 10), e como não podemos ter um dígito 10 faz-se exceção para ignorar o resto que dê 1 e trata como se o dígito verificador já seja 0 sem mais nada a fazer. Se der outro número termina o cálculo do dígito pegando 11 e subtraindo esse resto, achando o resultado final.

Eu testei e dá o mesmo resultado das outras respostas, se o meu gerar apenas o que eles geram, obviamente. Até onde eu sei as regras do CPF são estas, se alguém ver alguma regra extra que não foi respeitada eu posso melhorar.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;
using System.Linq;

WriteLine(GerarCpf(Uf.SP));
WriteLine(GerarCpf());

static string GerarCpf(Uf uf = Uf.NA) {
    Random random = new();
    int[] digitos = new int[11];
    int soma = 0, soma2 = 0;
    do {
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitos[i] = random.Next(10);
            soma += digitos[i] * (10 - i);
            soma2 += digitos[i] * (11 - i);
        }
        digitos[8] = uf == Uf.NA ? random.Next(10) : (int)uf;
        soma += digitos[8] * 2;
        soma2 += digitos[8] * 3;
    } while (Repetidos(digitos));
    var resto = soma % 11;
    digitos[9] = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    soma2 += digitos[9] * 2;
    resto = soma2 % 11;
    digitos[10] = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    return string.Join("", digitos.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
}

static bool Repetidos(int[] digitos) {
    var val = digitos[0];
    return digitos.Take(9).All(x => x == val);
}

enum Uf {
    AC = 2, AL = 4, AP = 2, AM = 2, BA = 5, CE = 3, DF = 1, ES = 7, GO = 1, MA = 3, MT = 1, MS = 1, MG = 6, PA = 2, PB = 4, PR = 9, PE = 4, PI = 3, RJ = 7, RN = 4, RS = 0, RO = 2, RR = 2, SC = 9, SP = 8, SE = 5, TO = 1, NA = -1
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/X9EV2K). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ddvxlS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Cpf.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a resposta já aceita, existe mais uma verificação que deve ser feita para gerar cpfs válidos. O cpf não pode ser composto de todos os dígitos iguais, como 111.111.111-11, 222.222.222-22 e por aí vai.

Também podemos fazer um padding na string, para garantir o comprimento de 9 caracteres sem limitar a faixa do número aleatório.

```
public string GerarCpf()
{

    var random = new Random();

    int soma = 0;
    int resto = 0;
    int[] multiplicadores = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
    string semente;

    do
    {
        semente = random.Next(1, 999999999).ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
    }
    while (
        semente == "000000000"
        || semente == "111111111"
        || semente == "222222222"
        || semente == "333333333"
        || semente == "444444444"
        || semente == "555555555"
        || semente == "666666666"
        || semente == "777777777"
        || semente == "888888888"
        || semente == "999999999"
    );

    for (int i = 1; i < multiplicadores.Count(); i++)
        soma += int.Parse(semente[i - 1].ToString()) * multiplicadores[i];

    resto = soma % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
        resto = 0;
    else
        resto = 11 - resto;

    semente += resto;
    soma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < multiplicadores.Count(); i++)
        soma += int.Parse(semente[i].ToString()) * multiplicadores[i];

    resto = soma % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
        resto = 0;
    else
        resto = 11 - resto;

    semente = semente + resto;

    return semente;

}
```

Também podemos quebrar a lógica do dígito verificador já que praticamente vamos executar ela 2x.
Não testei o código abaixo mas se não funcionar é algo bem parecido ;)

```
public string GerarCpf()
{

    var random = new Random();
    string semente;

    do
    {
        semente = random.Next(1, 999999999).ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
    }
    while (
        semente == "000000000"
        || semente == "111111111"
        || semente == "222222222"
        || semente == "333333333"
        || semente == "444444444"
        || semente == "555555555"
        || semente == "666666666"
        || semente == "777777777"
        || semente == "888888888"
        || semente == "999999999"
    );

    semente += CalcularDigitoVerificador(semente).ToString();
    semente += CalcularDigitoVerificador(semente).ToString();
    return semente;

}

public int CalcularDigitoVerificador(string semente)
{
    int soma = 0;
    int resto = 0;
    int[] multiplicadores = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

    var iFinal = multiplicadores.Count();
    var iInicial = iFinal - semente.Count;

    for (int i = iInicial; i < iFinal; i++)
        soma += int.Parse(semente[i - iInicial].ToString()) * multiplicadores[i];

    resto = soma % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
        resto = 0;
    else
        resto = 11 - resto;

    return resto;

}
```

E por último, embora sua pergunta seja sobre c#, selenium tem APIs para várias linguagens. Postei uma versão bem parecida desse [algoritmo (gera inscrições estaduais) em JavaScript no github](http://marcoluglio.github.io/inscricaoestadualcpfcnpj/index.htm).